# Replace all after only one dot (last dot) in email (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table:

```
id  MyText
1   aa.dd@mail.com
2   aa@mail.com
```

```
  `declare @MyTable table ([id] int primary key clustered, MyText varchar(100))
   insert into @MyTable ([id], MyText)
   select 1, 'aa.dd@mail.com'
   union all select 2, 'aa@mail.com' 

   UPDATE @MyTable
   SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX('.', MyText) - 1) + '.test'
   WHERE CHARINDEX('.', MyText) > 0`
```

I need to try In the email field, replace the last part (everything that comes after the last dot) with "test"
For example:

```
'aa.dd@gmail.com' - aa.dd@mail.test
'aa@mail.com' - aa@mail.test
'aa@mail.maill.mailll.com' - aa@mail.maill.mailll.test
```

but this solution replaces immediately after finding the first point and substitutes .test

in MySQL, I could use -SUBSTRING(INDEX(email, '.', -1))

Comment: Could you tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `REVERSE` function on the main string, then, because it is only the last dot you look for, find the first occurrence and subtract from the total string length, then you will get the position of the last dot so you can replace it.

So smth in this direction:

`UPDATE @MyTable SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, LEN(MyText) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(MyText)) + 1) + '.test' WHERE CHARINDEX('.', MyText) > 0`
`

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `LEFT` and `REVERSE` as follows :

```
UPDATE @MyTable
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, LEN(MyText) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(MyText))) + '.test'
WHERE CHARINDEX('.', MyText) > 0;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZWiqwpEY)